# python is there an inbuilt in way to return a list generator instead of list from random.sample

Tags: python, random

I use `random.sample` to sample from a very large range depending on the input load. Sometimes the sample itself is very large and since it is a list it occupies a lot of memory.

The application does not necessarily use all the value in the list. 
It would be great if `random.sample` can return a list generator instead of a list itself.

Right now I have a wrapper that divides the large input range into equal sized buckets and use `randint` to select a random number from each `n / sample_size` buckets.

edit: In my case input is continuous, I had this wrapper function to simulate random.sample as a generator but this is not truly replicating the functionality as it skips some elements in the end.

```
import random
def samplegen( start, end, sample_size ):
   bktlen = ( end - start ) / sample_size
   for i in xrange( sample_size ): #this skips the last modulo elements
      st = start + (i * bktlen)
      yield random.randrange( st, st + bktlen )
```

Comment: To do `random.sample` as a generator, you have to keep track of the items you've already yielded so you can avoid using them again. This will use just as much memory as returning a list.

Comment: @kindall that is why I am splitting the input range into buckets and selecting only one number from each bucket and the number of buckets is based on sample size. I should have mentioned the input is a continuous range of number like xrange( 0, 1000000 )

Comment: @user881300 How is `random.sample` of `xrange(0, 1000000)` a problem? That's not large.

Comment: @user881300 And does it matter that the order or the sample is random, or would it be ok if it were sorted?

Comment: How is what you are doing different from `random.randrange(1000000)` which doesn't generate a list?  Are you controlling for duplicates or not?

Comment: @user881300 And what does *"The application does not necessarily use all the value in the list"* mean? When/why does it not?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I gave that as an example. I mean the consumer for the sampled list does not index into it and only iterates through half of the sampled item most of the time. I generate this like 1000s of time so want to conserve some memory. Order does not matter as long as the sampling is random. Right now the wrapper I have maintains the order as it goes through the buckets in order...

Comment: @cdlane `randrange` gives me just one element. I need the equivalent of `random.sample` without generating a list of samples.

Comment: @user881300 What do you mean? Is `xrange(0, 1000000)` not a *representative* example? Then it's a *misleading* example and you'd better tell us what sizes you're actually dealing with.

Comment: @StefanPochmann my input range has some half a billion elements and the sample size varies from `0% - 100%` and I generate 1000s of samples of varying size

Comment: On further thought, if you don't need the original list order, you could `random.shuffle()` it and just iterate over the first `n` items from it. Of course if you're going to use the list for something else later, that won't do.

Answer (score 2):

Since you commented that the order doesn't matter (I had asked whether it must be random or can be sorted), this might be an option:

```
import random

def sample(n, k):
    """Generate random sorted k-sample of range(n)."""
    for i in range(n):
        if random.randrange(n - i) < k:
            yield i
            k -= 1
```

That goes through the numbers and includes each in the sample with probability
numberOfNumbersStillNeeded / numberOfNumbersStillLeft.

Demo:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
        print(list(sample(100, 10)))

[7, 16, 41, 50, 55, 56, 61, 76, 89, 96]
[5, 13, 24, 28, 34, 35, 40, 64, 80, 95]
[9, 18, 19, 36, 38, 39, 61, 73, 84, 85]
[23, 24, 26, 28, 40, 53, 62, 76, 77, 91]
[2, 12, 21, 41, 60, 68, 70, 72, 90, 91]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like the following -- the set `seen` only grows to a function of `k`, not necessarily to the size of `population`:

```
import random

def sample(population, k):
    seen = set()

    for _ in range(k):
        element = random.randrange(population)
        while element in seen:
            element = random.randrange(population)

        yield element
        seen.add(element)

for n in sample(1000000, 10):
    print(n)
```

Another approach might be to work with your original bucket design but with non-uniform buckets whose indexes themselves are randomly sampled:

```
import random

def samplegen(start, end, sample_size):
    random_bucket_indices = random.sample(range(start, end), sample_size)
    sorted_bucket_indices = sorted(random_bucket_indices) + [end + 1]
    for index in random_bucket_indices:
        yield random.randrange(index, sorted_bucket_indices[sorted_bucket_indices.index(index) + 1])
```

Comment: `while element in seen: pass` is going to run forever (if it runs at all). I think you want to repeat the assignment of `element` in that loop.

Comment: @cdlane apart from issue mentioned by @Blckknght, this uses `o( k )` memory which is what the list generated by `random.sample` uses but yes the `list` returned will exist for a long time after the call gets over vs the set is immediately cleaned up.

Comment: I think this is still a useful approach (if the implementation was correct), since the set uses `O(number of elements yielded so far)` space, which might not be `O(k)` if the consumer of the generator quits early without iterating over most of the sample. It's does use `O(k)` space in the worst case, but that's not really a big downside, since it's the same as `random.sample`.

Comment: @Blckknght, thanks for catching my screwup and your analysis!  I've patched it but might try to rearrange it a bit to make it cleaner.